# foreach controller not working correctly with variables

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

Im trying to loop over my user defined variables and add them to cookie manager.

Here is how I set it up:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But when I look at the results it only takes the FIRST var and uses that for ALL of the loops. So HTTP Cookie Manager is only replacing the first var.

This behavior is unexpected, have I set something up wrong? I added the debug sampler and I can see the vars are changing but for some reason http cookie manager is not replacing them

Comment: Hi any feedback on answer ? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define variable:

> cookie_matchNr set to 3

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor