# How can I access the cookie manager in beanshell?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, beanshell

I have seen many examples but none seem to work.

This is what I have setup:

[image]

I'm using a foreach to loop through my variables and have Cookie Manager use them:
[image]

I want the beanshell to clear the cookies in the cookie manager on each loop so they get re-added from my vars, but I can't seem to access it.

I tried the following:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;

manager = sampler.getCookieManager();
```

That gives me this error:

```
Attempt to resolve method: getCookieManager() on undefined variable or class name: sampler
```

I tried doing this:

```
CookieManager cManager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getCookieManager();
```

But that gives me this error:

```
Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Method getCookieManager() not found in class'org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BeanShellSampler'
```

Edit:
So as per a suggested solution I tried this:

[image]

And then this:

[image]

But that gives me this error:

```
2017/10/13 12:26:31 ERROR - jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 PostProcessor javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method clear() on null object
```

Comment: What fixed your issue? Upgrade to 3.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Beanshell because of Performance and it will be removed in future versions.

- Add a [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) on the first HTTP Request
- Select Groovy
- Check "Cache compiled script if available"
- Add following code:

`import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
     import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
     CookieManager cm = sampler.getCookieManager();
     cm.clear();`

This is what it should look like

[image]

Comment: If i do that when I call clear I get: "Cannot invoke method clear() on null object"

Comment: you used a Post, I required a pre processor

Comment: Post processor throws the same error updated to show post processor not working either

Comment: what. version of jmeter are you using ? add a null check on cm

Comment: Version 3.1 r1770033. But its still null, it shouldn't null. Im setting the cookie in the Cookie Manager and I see it for each HTTP request in the results tree so I know its getting set

Comment: In 3.3 it is working fine for me but I didn't test within For Eeach controller. See my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732290/foreach-controller-not-working-correctly-with-variables for it

Comment: what was the problem, why didn’t it work initially for you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take Cookie Manage from JMeter context:

```
CookieManager cm= ctx.getCurrentSampler().getCookieManager();
```

Currently you are getting it from `sampler` which is irrelevant.